# Oracle SQL get the first and last records from an ordered dataset

Tags: sql, oracle

The software I am working on has a requirement to get the first and last records of an ordered dataset. Dataset is ordered by a date column.

The data I have:

```
--table "notes":
--    ordered by this
--                |
--                V
note_id      date_created attribute1  attribute2  ... -- I want to get
-----------------------------------------------------
596          2014/01/20   ...         ...         ... -- <- this
468          2014/02/28   ...         ...         ...
324          2014/03/01   ...         ...         ...
532          2014/04/08   ...         ...         ...
465          2014/05/31   ...         ...         ... -- <- and this
```

Desired output:

```
596          2014/01/20   ...         ...         ...
465          2014/05/31   ...         ...         ...
```

Comment: Which version of oracle?

Comment: @Vargan: 11gR2, but I thought to make it a generic Oracle SQL question. So the later visitors can benefit too.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by date_created) as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 or seqnum = cnt;
```

In Oracle 12, you can also do:

```
select t.*
from t
order by date_created
fetch first 1 rows only
union all
select t.*
from t
order by date_created desc
fetch first 1 rows only;
```

Comment: Oracle has ROWNUM, so first query can be simplified

Comment: @Bulat using row_number is more safe than using rownum, analytic function apply to the result set after the result set got ready, but oracle docs don't tell us when rownum is generated

Comment: As soon as it is generated for all rows I don't see any difference. row_number() is a better solution because it is not Oracle specific.

Comment: @Bulat the problem is that you don't control the first record even if you use the `order by` clause, the oracle docs don't tell you when the `rownum` column generates for a result set, so you can't be sure that seqnum = 1 is the record with the earliest date. Forget about Oracle specific stuff, you buy the most powerful RDBMS in the world, you spend really a lot of money, why do you need to limit yourself with the ANSI standard?

Comment: Cause few years later someone will decide to move it to SQL Server. You are right about ROWNUM as it is calculated before the ORDER BY.

Answer (score 6):

If I got it right, try this:

```
select t1.*
  from YOUR_TABLE t1
     , (
        select min(note_id) keep(dense_rank first order by date_created) min_val
             , max(note_id) keep(dense_rank last order by date_created) max_val
          from YOUR_TABLE
       ) t2
 where t1.note_id = t2.min_val
    or t1.note_id = t2.max_val
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Select * from emp where rowid  =(select min(rowid) from emp)
Union
Select * from emp where rowid  =(select max(rowid) from emp);
```

Comment: rowid contains information necessary to locate a row; its min or max value does not necessarily reflect the first and last row; see https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/pseudocolumns008.htm#SQLRF00254 -- rowid is derived by the data object number of the object, the data block in the data file in which the row resides, position of the row in the data block and the data file.  If the table gets reorganized, compressed, etc. the rowid will change.  99% of the time your query may work, but 1% can cost you.